# Swift is using the wrong subscript overload. How can I get it to use the right one?

Tags: swift

I'm writing UI testing code using XCTest. Here is my test method:

```
func testLandingUI() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let headerExpectedMessage = "Title"
    let headerLabel = app.staticTexts[headerExpectedMessage]

    XCTAssert(headerLabel.exists)
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ExampleUITests.swift:38:19: error: value of type 'Any?' has no member 'exists'
    XCTAssert(headerLabel.exists)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~
```

What's strange about this error is that I expected `headerLabel` to be of type `XCUIElement`, not `Any?`.

`XCUIApplication.staticTexts` is an `XCUIElementQuery`, which has a subscript method declared thusly:

```
open class XCUIElementQuery : NSObject, XCUIElementTypeQueryProvider {
    ...
    open subscript(key: String) -> XCUIElement { get }
    ...
}
```

What I believe is happening is the `subscript` method in `XCUIElementQuery` is not being selected by Swift's overload resolution. Instead, it's selecting this category on `NSObject`:

```
@interface NSObject (MyCategory)

- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString*)key;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(NSString*)key;

@end
```

I verified that if I remove that category from my project, the error goes away. Assume that removing that category is not possible (because it's not). Is there any way to get Swift to use the correct `subscript` method?

**Minimal test case that shows the problem**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0fm5ennco7t2ua/SubscriptCategoryTest.zip?dl=1
(note that the error is in the UI tests, so press command-shift-U to see the error)

**EDIT**: It looks like the problem only shows up if the category defines `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`. Interestingly, I get a slightly different error if both getter and setter are defined vs. just the setter.

Comment: did you try changing "let headerLabel = app.staticTexts[headerExpectedMessage]" to "let headerLabel: XCUIElement  = app.staticTexts[headerExpectedMessage]"

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and I get a different error message: "Cannot subscript a value of type XCUIElementQuery" on that headerLabel assignment line.

Comment: So it's telling you it's not the type you expected it to be... What type does the compiler think it is? Hold your cursor over the variable name. It seems it is XCUIElementQuery -- so what does your definition of staticTexts look like?

Comment: `staticTexts` is part of the `XCUIElementTypeQueryProvider` protocol, to which `XCUIApplication` conforms. The definition looks like this: `@property (readonly, copy) XCUIElementQuery *staticTexts;`

Comment: That code works for me, what Swift/Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Can (also) not reproduce. If you select the opening bracket `[` in `app.staticTexts[headerExpectedMessage]` and then "Navigate -> Jump To Definition" , what do you get?

Comment: Xcode 8.3.2. It's possible that in order to reproduce this, the NSObject category needs to be in a separate framework that is being imported by the Swift file (that's how it's set up in my project). I'm trying to get a minimal test case set up now that I can add to the question.

Comment: @Sulthan I added a small project that duplicates the issue.

Comment: @JoshHinman That category is made to break subscripting. I guess you will have to use `staticTexts.matching(identifier: headerExpectedMessage)` or whatever is the method counterpart of the subscripting.

Comment: @Sulthan That works, but it's strange, right? Seems like a bug in Swift--a category on a superclass shouldn't be overriding a method on a subclass. And in case you're curious, the actual category is a shortcut for key-value coding. Not something I would have written, but I inherited it, so it is what it is.

Comment: @JoshHinman I don't think it overrides the method but it changes the return type of the method. I guess that casting that using `as! XCUIElementQuery` would probably still work.

Comment: I have just tested that `as! XCUIElement` works, even invoking `objectForKeyedSubscript` directly works. So it's only the subscripting operator. It could be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler is confused, you need to help it....
Given this example:

```
let example1: Any? = "1" 
let example2: Any = "2"
```

You have two issues (it looks like you have an optional...)

```
if example1.exists {  // won't work - I got your error message

}
if (example2 as AnyObject).exists { // works with a cast

}
```

I believe if you correct identify the type of the variable it will solve your problem. It is matching the NSObject category only because it didn't match something more specific.

Comment: I've tried different variations of adding explicit type hints and have not yet found one that works.